# MySQL Server randomly shutting down

Tags: mysql

After infrequent intervals, MySQL server keeps **shutting down**.

I can't find what is triggering this shutdown.

I get errors like:

- > ERROR 1053 (08S01): Server shutdown in progress
- > ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
- > No connection. Trying to reconnect...

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 And MySQL 5.7.26.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I found the issue it was because a script was restating mysql.

Comment: Since you found a solution to your question, consider adding your solution as an answer so others with this issue can more easily find it.

Comment: I have a script which checks if server is running fine By checking time taken to load a given page and also connecting to MYSQL.

If the page could not be loaded for 3 minutes then it world restart all its services.